# How to generate a list of all collections in 11ty

Tags: javascript, static-site, eleventy

I have a simple Eleventy site v0.11.0

I'm using tag in the front matter to generate collections.

Ex:

```
---
title: Some post
tags:
 - apple
 - banana
 - soccer
---
```

I want to show a list each of each tag / collection but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I can get it working by creating a new collection in my .eleventy file...

```
    eleventyConfig.addCollection("tagsList", function(collectionApi) {
        const tagsList = new Set();
        collectionApi.getAll().map( item => {
            if (item.data.tags) { // handle pages that don't have tags
                item.data.tags.map( tag => tagsList.add(tag))
            }
        });
        return tagsList;
    });
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for tag in collections.tagsList %}
    <a href="/tags/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But this feels hacky and I suspect there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Everything about using 11ty feels hacky...

Comment: What I don't get is... how do we generate the folder per tag?
`/tag/demo`,  `tag/test`. They don't seem to be generated by just creating a new collection?

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer seems quite correct to me. Some comments:

- You are creating [custom global data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global-custom/) by using the `addGlobalData()` method, but accessing the data like it's a [collection](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/) (`collections.tagsList`). I don't know how that's possible, but maybe I just have some problems on my end because I can't get `addGlobalData()` to work at all.
- An alternative to creating custom global data (`addGlobalData()`) would be to create a collection (`addCollection()`). This is what I do on my 11ty site: [I create a collection of tags in my `.eleventy.config.js`](https://github.com/mtsknn/mtsknn.fi/blob/de046c93bf63ad386749f80e51daffa24946ba15/.eleventy.js#L23-L29). Looks like [11ty/eleventy-base-blog also uses a collection of tags](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog/blob/032e8d3cb5f1a2d84bf8ec6e9c88f26a105ae250/.eleventy.js#L40-L67).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array. Your code uses `map()` twice, but doesn't use their return values (i.e. the new arrays). If the new arrays are not needed, using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would make more sense.

Here's how I would create the collection (very similar to your solution):

```js
config.addCollection('tagsList', (collectionApi) => {
  const tagsSet = new Set()
  collectionApi.getAll().forEach((item) => {
    if (!item.data.tags) return
    item.data.tags.forEach((tag) => tagsSet.add(tag))
  })
  return tagsSet
})
```

Usage in templates would be the same.

Bonus: with filtering (excludes tags "foo" and "bar") and alphabetical sorting:

```js
config.addCollection('tagsList', (collectionApi) => {
  const tagsSet = new Set()
  collectionApi.getAll().forEach((item) => {
    if (!item.data.tags) return
    item.data.tags
      .filter((tag) => !['foo', 'bar'].includes(tag))
      .forEach((tag) => tagsSet.add(tag))
  })
  return [...tagsSet].sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))
})
```

Comment: Good catch. addGlobalData was a copy paste mistake. I’m doing addCollection like you. I’ll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

my version of the working code

```
      // Display tag list on page
  eleventyConfig.addCollection('tagsList', function (collectionApi) {
    const tagsList = new Set()
    collectionApi.getAll().map((item) => {
      if (item.data.tags) {
        // handle pages that don't have tags
        item.data.tags.filter((tag) => !['yourtag'].includes(tag)).map((tag) => tagsList.add(tag))
      }
    })
    return tagsList
  })
```